# Django : Order drop-down lists in the admin interface

Tags: django, admin, dropdownlistfor

i try to order properties in the admin but it does not work

model

```
class Physic(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name=_('name'), null=True, blank=True,)
    lapropriete = models.CharField(_('property'), max_length=100)....

class Essai_Temperature(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Material,                                                 
    nature_unit = models.ForeignKey(Property, 
    choix = ChainedForeignKey(Physic, verbose_name=_('properties'), null....
```

form

```
class  Essai_TemperatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Essai_Temperature

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Essai_TemperatureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choix'].queryset = Physic.objects.order_by('-lapropriete')
```

admin

```
class Essai_TemperatureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Essai_Temperature
    form = Essai_TemperatureForm
    extra = 5
```

what is the problem here ?

maybe choix ?

I have dropdown list ('Hardness Vickers (GPa)', Shear Modulus (MPa)'......

Comment: What is `ChainedForeignKey`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [`ordering` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) of the `ModelAdmin` (which will also work on the `TabularInline` - [it previously didn't work but has been fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13862))

```
class Essai_TemperatureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Essai_Temperature
    form = Essai_TemperatureForm
    ordering = ('-choix__lapropriete',)
    extra = 5
```

Comment: I have the error: Cannot resolve keyword 'lapropriete' into field. Choices are: choix,id, name, nature_unit,...

Comment: It should be 'choix__lapropiete' but as @DanielRoseman points out, it depends on what ChainedForeignKey is. Not sure why its downvoted

Comment: I have used 'Django smart select' to chain 'choix' and 'nature_unit' ChainedForeignKey depends of nature_unit

Comment: ok it works !! ordering = ('-choix__lapropriete',) is the solution thanks